# using git-flow with multiple git repositories per project/app?

Tags: git, git-flow

At my current place of work we are using git-flow, we use the standard buckets (develop in develop, release in master, feature this, feature that, etc).

We are using a large number of git repositories (per project) where often I have to start a 'feature' in more than one git. Typically around three git repos.

```
myApp
    git: bitofcode1
    git: scripts
    git: library
```

I try to use the same feature name 'feature-change-whatever' across all the three git repos but it feels to me that the git-flow model is not appropriate for dealing with new features in a project spread across multiple repos.

```
myApp
    git: bitofcode1 (feature-change-whatever)
    git: scripts  (feature-change-whatever)
    git: library  (feature-change-whatever)
```

My thoughts are that in order to use git-flow with 'myapp' I would be better merging my 3 different git repositories into a single larger one.
Are there any other ways of addressing this while using git-flow ?

Comment: In [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/choosing-between-single-or-multiple-projects-in-a-git-repository) there's a similar question, though it's not specific to git-flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [gitslave](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/): Coordinated multi-repository super-projects for Git
>
> gitslave creates a group of related repositories—a superproject repository and a number of slave repositories—all of which are concurrently developed on and on which all git operations should normally operate; so when you branch, each repository in the project is branched in turn. Similarly when you commit, push, pull, merge, tag, checkout, status, log, etc; each git command will run on the superproject and all slave repositories in turn.

This way you can (as stated) create feature branches across multiple repositories in a "single larger" repo. See the [gitslave basic tutorial](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/tutorial-basic.html).

Unfortunately the most recent version at the time of writing [gitslave (2.0.2) is outdated](http://sourceforge.net/p/gitslave/bugs/) with respect to some changes in plain `git`'s output.

**Edit:** [forked gitslave and applied some basic patches to get it working again.](https://github.com/joelpurra/gitslave) Check it out!

With [`brew`](http://brew.sh/) on Mac OS X you can now:

```bash
brew tap joelpurra/joelpurra
brew install --devel joelpurra/joelpurra/gitslave
```